# return json if ajax call otherwise return html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I try to a find a method to return a json if it is a ajax call else I want the HTML .

I am not using a framework or a templating ...

this is what I done 
in my first page

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url : 'XXXXX.php',
    data : {'id' : id_test },
    cache : false , 
    success : function(html) {
        console.log(html);
    }
})
```

And in my XXXXX.php page I have

```
<?php
    $my_id = $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        ....
        return json_encode($my_value);
    } else {
        ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                bla bla ba bla bla
            </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }    
?>
```

I am not sure I am using the good solution.

Comment: You can use a $_GET var such as: `ajax.php?id=X&type=ajax`. Also you can separate your file into 2 and have one for the ajax request a the other for html which i think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, there are *two* (distinct ...) sets of URLs that the host provides:

1. URLs that are intended to be directly accessed by the browser, and which return HTML.
2. URLs that are intended to be accessed using (only) AJAX calls, and which return JSON (or XML).

URLs in the second group are strictly for *program-to-program* communication:   the technique is sometimes formally referred to as **Remote Procedure Calls (RPC).**   A (JavaScript) *program* on the client side is talking to *another program* on the host side, and then *programmatically* acting upon the response in some way.

While your technique *could* work, and superficially seems to me to be correctly coded, I have almost never actually seen it done and would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is the correct way but not all servers/frameworks provide this variable so having other checks in place will be important. For example you can add `contentType: "application/json"`, to your jQuery ajax options then you check for `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]` value:

```
if($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] === 'application/json') {
     //....
}
```